# If an operator commutes with the Hamiltonian then do all of its projectors commute also?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, commutator

Suppose I have an (self-adjoint) operator (representing an observable) $O$ which commutes with the system Hamiltonian $H$. Does it follow that $[P_O(\Delta),H] = 0$ where $P_O(\Delta)$ is an arbitrary projection operator onto the space corresponding to the subset of $O$'s spectrum, $\Delta$?

I'm not sure exactly how to go about proving it though I feel it should be true; since $O$ can be decomposed into projectors I have a *sense* that if $O$ commutes with $H$ then so should every part of its decomposition. This question arises in the context of a discussion of *constants of motion*. The definition thereof is usually to say that it commutes with the Hamiltonian, with the subsequent claim that not only all expectation values but also every probability distribution (in every possible state) are unchanged with time. I believe I need to be able to show my claim in the first paragraph so as to prove it.

Comment: Its is evident by inspecting two diagonal matrices, one (H) bigger or of the same size than the other (O), no? you want a hidebound proof?

Comment: TIL the word "hidebound", thank you :) I agree it's evident but, yes, if such a proof can be supplied I would appreciate it. I can convince myself of things without actually showing them rather often. @CosmasZachos

Comment: In finite dimensions, it holds for two hermitian operators $A,B$ that $[A,B]=0 \iff [P_a, P_b]=0$ for all associated projection operators $P_a,P_b$ of the respective spectral decomposition. A neat proof is given in e.g. Isham's book (and in contrast to the given answer here, it does not use the result that there is a common eigenbasis; rather this follows from the above assertion).

Answer (score 4):

In general it is false for unbounded selfadjoint operators. There are examples by Nelson of operators which commute on a dense invariant domain which is a core for them, but the spectral measure do not.

However, if $A$ is selfadjoint and bounded, thus everywhere defined, and $B$ is densely defined and selfadjoint and $ABx =BAx$ for all $x\in D(B)$, then then the spectral measures commute as well (and thus the spectral measures also commute with the operators).

A proof (of this fact and several other related facts) appears in my books of spectral theory and mathematical foundations of quantum theories.

Comment: Interesting. What is your working definition of commuting unbounded self-adjoint operators? The one I know asserts just that, that two unbounded s-a operators are said to commutenin their maximal common domain, if the spectral projections commute on the same maximal common domain.

Comment: $ABx=BAx$ for all $x\in D(AB) \cap D(BA)$. This is the definition of generic commutativy. Next there is the notion of "strong" commutativity of $A$ and $B$ which means that the spectral measures of them commute. That is equivalent to $f(A)B \subset Bf(A)$ for every Borel-measurable *bounded* function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For finite dimensions, an easy way to prove it is to use that for an operator $A$, the eigenspace projectors are all polynomials in $A$ (namely, the polynomial which is zero at all eigenvalues except for the chosen one, where it is one). Since the operators commute, any polynomial in them will also commute.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite clear by the following facts: since $H$ and $O$ commute they can be both diagonalized. Hence they can both be represented by simulateneously diagonal matrices. The projector into a subspace $\Delta$ of the spectrum of $O$ will also be diagonal and hence it must commute with $H$. If you want a detailed proof, here it goes.

Let $O$ be a Hermitian operator that commutes with another Hermitian operator $H$. Since $O$ and $H$ commute they have a common basis of eigenvectors, let's call it $|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle$ where $\lambda$ labels the eigenvalue of $O$, $\kappa$ labels the eigenvalue of $H$ and $\sigma$ labels possible degeneracies. The states are normalized $$\langle \lambda,\kappa,\sigma|\lambda',\kappa',\sigma'\rangle=\delta_{\lambda,\lambda'}\delta_{\kappa,\kappa'}\delta_{\sigma,\sigma'}\tag{1}$$

and we have

$$O|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle=a_\lambda|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle,\quad H|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle=\omega_\kappa|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle\tag{2}.$$

Now let $\Delta$ be a subset of the spectrum of $O$. The corresponding projector can be written as

$$P_O(\Delta)=\sum_{\lambda\in \Delta}\sum_{\kappa,\sigma}|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle \langle \lambda,\kappa,\sigma|\tag{3}$$

Now it is clear that $P_O(\Delta)$ commutes with $H$

\begin{eqnarray}P_0(\Delta)H&=&\sum_{\lambda\in \Delta}\sum_{\kappa,\sigma}|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle\langle \lambda,\kappa,\sigma|H\\ 
&=&\sum_{\lambda\in \Delta}\sum_{\kappa,\sigma}|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle \langle \lambda,\kappa,\sigma|\omega_\kappa\\
&=&\sum_{\lambda\in\Delta}\sum_{\kappa,\sigma}\omega_\kappa|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle\langle \lambda,\kappa,\sigma|\\
&=&\sum_{\lambda\in \Delta}\sum_{\kappa,\sigma}H|\lambda,\kappa,\sigma\rangle\langle \lambda,\kappa,\sigma|\\
&=&HP_0(\Delta),\tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

as we wanted to show.