# Showing that time ordering does not matter for the measurement of commuting observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, commutator, observables

Suppose I have two observables $R$ and $S$ who are represented by operator $R$ and $S$ which commute (I will hereafter ignore the distinction between observables and the operators representing them), and fix the state of interest $\rho$. Let $A$ be the event that eigenvalues of $R$ in the set $\Delta_A$ are measured at $t_A$, and let be the event that eigenvalues of $S$ in the set $\Delta_B$ are measured at $t_B$. Suppose I want the probability $Prob(A\wedge B|\rho)$. Ballentine (Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development), taking the Heisenberg picture, tells me (though he does not prove it, I am willing to accept it) that the appropriate projection operator corresponding to this compound event are the projection operators onto the given eigenspaces of the corresponding operators $R(t_A), S(t_B)$ (incidentally, it's not clear to me how one proves this is the right correpsonding projection operator, but presumably more rigorous textbooks prove a correspondence between subspaces of Hilbert spaces and events on some probability space). The corresponding projection operators are
$$M_{R(t_A)}(\Delta A) = \sum_{r_n \in \Delta A} U^\dagger{t_A}| r_n \rangle \langle r_n | U(t_A)$$
$$M_{S(t_B)}(\Delta B) = \sum_{s_n \in \Delta B} U^\dagger{t_b}| s_n \rangle \langle s_n | U(t_B)$$
where I have used that eigenvectors in the Heisenberg picture evolve "backwards" and maintain the same eigenvalues as at $t=0$. Now the Born rule says that
$$Prob(A\wedge B|\rho) = Tr\left[\rho M_{R(t_A)}(\Delta A)M_{S(t_B)}(\Delta B)\right].$$
But (and here is my question) Ballentine goes on to write " the order of the times $t_a$ and $t_b$ at which the two measurements are performed is irrelevant, as is apparent from symmetry of (9.26) with respect to the two projection operators." This seems to suggest that if $t_A$ is swapped with $t_B$, then I will get the same thing. That is, in my notation,
$$Tr\left[\rho M_{R(t_A)}(\Delta A)M_{S(t_B)}(\Delta B)\right] = Tr\left[\rho M_{R(t_B)}(\Delta A)M_{S(t_A)}(\Delta B)\right].$$
Note how the times have been swapped on the right-hand side.

But why should this be true? I take from a question like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754852/if-an-operator-commutes-with-the-hamiltonian-then-do-all-of-its-projectors-commu) that it is true that if two operators commute, then so too do all their projection operators. Thus all of the projection operators of $R(0)$ and $S(0)$ ought to commute. But why should this be true when each have evolved by some arbitrary time?

Comment: The time evolution is unitary (i.e. a unitary transformation), just compute the commutator of the time-evolved projectors...

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the text is saying. It is not saying that measurements of $A$ and $B$ at times $t_A$ and $t_B$ are equivalent to measurements of $B$ and $A$ at times $t_A$ and $t_B$. He means that the same mathematical expression for the joint probability holds whether $t_A > t_B$ or $t_A < t_B$.

Comment: But surely that is trivially true, whether or not these observables commute? That is, if the appropriate projection operator for a compound event is simply a product of projection operators for the individual events, then what you say must be true (since the relationship of $t_A$ to $t_B$ is then irrelevant since on or the other appears separately in each part of the product)? Perhaps I am not understanding, but there seems to be no physical relevance to such a fact. @knzhou

Comment: @TobiasFünke I did try, but it wasn't clear to me that $[U(t_A),U_(t_b)] = 0$ in general (I can't assume we have a time-independent Hamiltonian). Even if that were true, I can't see how the pass the projectors through the $U(t)$?

Comment: Well, that's precisely the point: it's trivially true for commuting observables when you look at the formula (that's why Ballentine says it's "apparent"), but the statement has content because it's _not_ true for noncommuting observables. For example, if a free particle has spin along $+z$ and you measure $S_z$ and then $S_x$, the $S_z$ measurement has a 100% chance of measuring up. But if you measure $S_x$ and then $S_z$, the $S_z$ measurement has a 50% chance of measuring up.

Comment: I think I agree, but given what you're written in that latter case, shouldn't that (in my case here) correspond to swapping the times at which the measurements are made? @knzhou

Comment: @EE18 Ah, good point... I have to check Ballentine's exact statements...

Comment: Hmm, I opened up Ballentine and I think it's actually simple if a bit confusing. Here Ballentine is talking about "filtering-type measurements", i.e. measurements where you select subsets of the particles which have some value for some observable, and _nothing happens in between_. That is, the Hamiltonian commutes with all the observables under consideration. So your statement is trivially true because $R(t_a) = R(t_b)$.

Comment: Certainly, when actual dynamics happens in between the measurements, all bets are off. For example, $S_x$ and $S_z$ commute but if you rotate the spin in between the measurements, then their measurements won't effectively commute.

Comment: I see, thank you for checking Ballentine for me, @knzhou . To confirm, you're saying my statement (and Ballentine's which I quoted) is trivially true because the commutativity at any two times is guaranteed by the assumed commutativity at time zero (because we allow no non-trivial time development between $t_A$ and $t_B$, so that $U(t_A) = U(t_B)$)?

Comment: Also, and as an side (happy to ask another question), were you convinced by Ballentine's assertion of Luders Rule (9.28)? It seems like his whole schtick has been to deny the necessity of collapse (among other things), and yet he just slides collapse in underhandedly seemingly without any proof? He just says the filtered state "can be regarded as preparing a new state that is represented by" the prediction of Luders rule, without saying why. @knzhou

Comment: First comment: yes. Second comment: I don't know since I haven't actually read Ballentine, you should ask a separate question!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to put a checkmark if you'd like to give your comment above as an answer. @knzhou

Comment: @knzhou As I think about it, I'm less convinced that Ballentine is saying no time evolution occurs between the two measurements. If you take a look at the discussion above (9.26) (which is before any mention of filter-type measurements in particular is made), it is tacitly suggested that whether we use $M_R(\Delta a)M_S(\Delta b)$ or $M_S(\Delta b)M_R(\Delta a)$ as the "projection operator that projects onto the subspace spanned by those common eigenvectors of $R$ and $S$ [as understood at given times in the Heis picture] with eigenvalues in the ranges $\Delta a$ and $\Delta b$, respectively".